# MS Office 2010 under Wine quits working

Tags: wine

although prefering LibreOffice I have to run MSO for file exchange with colleagues.

I had installed it from original CD under Wine using the original setup.exe
Word and Excel worked fine for more than a year. Since recently it crashed when opening any office file.

I tried a new MSO installation. This always crashes halfway with an MSO error message "cant install ...", leaving lots of junk files in my .wine folder.
I get the same result when using an older kernel. I think the reason might be a recent wine update or the like.

Al my other wine applications are working fine.

My system is: 
Ubuntu 12.04, 64-Bit, Kernel Linux 3.13.0-62-generic GNOME 3.4.2

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should modify your question to include the wine version you are currently using, and if you remember the one that was working.

Answer (score 0):

The wine version is 1.4, currently without using the wine repository, thus without updates to newer versions. 
Meanwhile and for another reason I restored a one year old image of the root partition and did all updates. Surprisingly now also the Wine/MSO installation works fine again. 
So currently the issue is solved, but what can I do to avoid further problems ?